# Wordpress: How can I make the posts in this 3-column layout have unequal heights?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Currently I have this 3 column layout in Wordpress, I'd like each image in the column to follow on from where the last one finished.

This is how the layout looks currently, a clear:both class is used.

[Current Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTkPS.png)

And this is how I would like it to look.

[Desired Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di7of.png)

I know how to create this sort of layout using CSS but I'm not sure how to insert each post into a container like this. I've tried many solutions online and they're either out-dated or just result in my page not working. The best I could get was putting all the posts in one class and applying clear:both when counter reached 3.

Here is my code :

```
<div id="content">
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php

if($i == 0) {
        echo '<div class="clear-row">';
        }
?>

<div class="column-one">
<p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
if($i == 3) {
    $i = 0;
    echo '</div>';
    }
    ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>

<?php

if($i > 0) {
    echo '</div>';
    }
?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p><?php         
endif; ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been trapped in the Wordpress dimension for days